# Finding density of the gas mixture

Tags: gas-laws

> A gas in a vessel is under pressure of $\pu{1800kPa}$. The design temperature of the tank is $\pu{423K}$. The gas consists of (by volume) $20\ \%$ of $\ce{CH4}$ and $80\ \%$ $\ce{N2}$. Estimate the density (in $\pu{kg/m^3}$) of the gas.

I can't just use the ideal gas law to find out the density of the mixture as there are two components, right?

$$\rho=\frac{pM_\mathrm r}{RT}$$

From the ideal gas law, I can also predict that vol% equals mol%. But with this, am I supposed to find the average value of $M_\mathrm r$ and then substitute it into the equation above?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Chem.SE! Is the last line actually "...of the gas _mixture_" in your question?

Comment: @GaurangTandon nope.

Comment: Yes.  What is the molar average molecular weight?  (Hint:  when we say 20% by volume, we mean that the mole fraction is 0.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You originally said that:

> The gas consists of 20vol%,CH4 and 80% N2...

This is a **fault in the question**. A gas cannot consist of *two other* gases and still remain a *gas*. Instead, it is now a **gas mixture**. (hence I had added the term "mixture" into your question, which I've now removed to retain the original meaning)

Once this is out of the way, you can think of density as: $$\begin{align}
\text{density}&=\frac{\text{total mass}}{\text{total volume}}\\\\\
&=\frac{n_1M_1+n_2M_2}{(n_1+n_2)RT/P}\\\\
&=\frac{P(n_1M_1+n_2M_2)}{(n_1+n_2)RT}\\\\
&=\frac{PM_{\text{avg}}}{RT}
\end{align}$$

and recall that volume percent is equivalent to mole percent, as you correctly did already. Substitute the correct values into this equation and you're good to go.

**PS:** I do not understand what you're denoting by $M_\mathrm r$. But, the formula you were using is identical to mine if you swap $M_\mathrm r$ with $M_\text{avg}$.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in 2nd equation, where you took $P$. You should have taken individual pressure of the gases. Hence the equation should be $\frac{n_1M_1+n_2M_3}{RT/P}$.

Comment: What are n1 and n2 in your equation? Is it would be a molar fraction which is equivalent to volume fraction and hence it should not be a mass fraction, right?